# Does Juno's UVS have any chance to spot Europa plumes?

Tags: planetary-science, atmosphere, jupiter, juno, europa

JIRAM has recently been proven to be useful to monitor the volcanic activity on Io, from a considerable distance.

Europa Clipper will have an ultraviolet spectrograph which be pretty much a copy of Juno's UVS.

So, do you think that it could in theory be able to give additional confirmation of the plumes detected by Hubble?

Answer (score 3):

There is a chance, if Juno can get close enough.  According to the [Planetary Society](http://www.planetary.org/blogs/guest-blogs/2016/0830-will-junos-instruments-observe-jupiters-moons.html) a distance of 40,000 km or less is needed to detect the plumes with the UVS.  Other instruments can detect the plumes at greater distance, up to 170,000 km, if the plumes contain fine particles.

Alas, getting close enough is not trivial.  The referenced site indicates that the spacecraft got inside 170,000 km from Europa once in 2017, but it does not give any later or future encounter dates.  No date is given for a fly-by within the UVS range of 40,000 km.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question: Juno is going to search for plumes, but rather than using UVS, it will use JunoCam and Stellar Reference Unit cameras. It is going to perform [a close flyby, 320 km, 29 September 2022](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r9bx1GcoqEE).

https://www.lpi.usra.edu/opag/meetings/opag2020fall/presentations/Bolton_6011.pdf

Comment: I've just asked [What is k2, how does it relate to Io's volcanism and how can Juno constrain its value?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/46887/7982) in Astronomy SE and linked to Bolton.  I've also fortified [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/53524/12102) with your video. Thanks for the great answer!